# while の下に一行足したら、それ以降の部分が繰り返し中に実行されなくなった

Tags: javascript

[mdnに掲載されている無限イテレーター](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator)の処理の流れが分からないので、挙動を確かめようと思い、`while` の直後に `console.log();`を挿入したら、繰り返し中に実行されていたはずの `yield` まで処理が到らず、単純な無限ループに陥りました。

```
function* idMaker(){
  var index = 0;
  while(true)
    console.log(index); //挿入してみた
    yield index++;
}

var gen = idMaker();

gen.next().value);
```

なぜですか？

Comment: 質問にクローズ票を投じます。オフトピックである理由: 単純なミスです。

Comment: タイポに近い単純なミスではありますが、非常にありがちな物ですので、残しておく価値がある Q&A だと思います。これ以後に同じミスの質問があれば、この質問との重複でクローズしていけますし、便利ではないでしょうか。そういった観点から、質問を編集し、少し一般化しました。（個人的にはもっと一般化して、イテレータ云々は完全に削除したコード例に置き換えてもよいと思います）

Answer (score 7, accepted):

無限イテレーターは関係ありません。構文の問題です。

```
// before
while(true)
    yield index++;

// after
while(true)
    console.log(index); //挿入してみた
    yield index++;
```

は

```
// before
while(true) {
    yield index++;
}

// after
while(true) {
    console.log(index); //挿入してみた
}
yield index++;
```

と解釈されます。